# Select 'Foo', 'Bar' not returning anything

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just started using Postgre SQL, I've been on Oracle and pl/sql for about 5 years no.

I'm trying to do a simple select statement and not getting the results I expect.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT 'Foo','Bar'
FROM   APP_TABLE
```

Where APP_TABLE is a table in my database. When ran, it returns 0 records. In Oracle that would return [Foo][Bar] as my results. Why does this not return anything in Postgres?

From some research I found that this works:

```
SELECT  'Foo','Bar' 
FROM    (Values('1'))
```

and I get the expected [Foo][Bar] as my results, but not sure this is the best approach. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because `APP_TABLE` is empty.

Comment: This works the same way in Postgres and Oracle. If there are no rows in `app_table` then Oracle won't return anything either. [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0dd1dc926d7c524f576f3e813f6b0fbe) vs [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0dd1dc926d7c524f576f3e813f6b0fbe)

Comment: Not only in postgreSQL, in any SQL database it should return 0 rows, WHEN app_table has no rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dummy `dual` table having only 1 row and 1 field.

You could also do it the  Postgres way, by not specifying any table at all:

```
SELECT 'Foo','Bar';
 ?column? | ?column?
----------+----------
 Foo      | Bar
(1 row)
```

Comment: you could create dual with no columns: `create table dual (); insert into dual default values;`

Comment: or `create table dual as select;`